# Are there any known "Iframe" issues on Microsoft Edge?

Tags: iframe, selenium-webdriver, jquery-selectors, automation, microsoft-edge

Are there any known "iframe" issues on Microsoft Edge? 
I am switching between frames while reading the web elements in my automation test and the test is not working at the moment.

**Found out that this the issue:**
Switching to frames or iframes (i.e., driver.switchTo().frame()) is likewise not implemented in this initial release, and neither is the advanced user interactions API (i.e,. the Actions class). In fairness, Microsoft has been completely forthcoming in what functionality the driver has implemented and what is missing. I fully expect that the driver will be receiving regular updates, and that the missing functionality will be added in the coming weeks and months.
Reference: http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com.au/2015/07/microsoft-releases-driver-for-microsoft.html

Comment: your issue is not clear from your post. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Use this URL to find out the driver status https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/webdriver/details/